# Boot repair doesn't help to repair my grub after ubuntu install on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue, boot-repair

I have problem with my dual boot, and i try boot repair which seems not work :/

I use windows 7 and Ubuntu on the same SSD, nammed /sda

You can find here the boot log url : 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10133221/

**UPDATE 1 :**

Hum, i fix boot using the windows command prompt and the command you given me, with success.

I try to boot windows, without success. So I restart ubuntu, and relaunch boot repair.

Message about boot problem disapear, but windows don't start :(

Here the log :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10163262/

**UPDATE 2 :**

I finnaly boot to windows using **hiren's boot cd** using bootmgr option, now i need to repair the boot.

Any repair i make (using mbrfix,etc) doesn't work at this time :(

Black screen on start ...

I'm lost.

**UPDATE 3 :**

```
=================== hexdump -n512 -C /dev/sda1
00000000  eb 63 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.c.NTFS    .....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 08 00 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00  ff 3f b2 15 00 00 00 00  |.........?......|
00000030  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff 23 5b 01 00 00 00 00  |.........#[.....|
00000040  f6 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  86 84 9a 25 13 e2 da 6a  |...........%...j|
00000050  00 00 00 00 fa 33 c0 8e  d0 bc 00 7c fb 68 c0 07  |.....3.....|.h..|
00000060  1f 1e 68 66 00 cb 88 16  0e 00 66 81 3e 03 00 4e  |..hf......f.>..N|
00000070  54 46 53 75 15 b4 41 bb  aa 55 cd 13 72 0c 81 fb  |TFSu..A..U..r...|
00000080  55 aa 75 06 f7 c1 01 00  75 03 e9 dd 00 1e 83 ec  |U.u.....u.......|
00000090  18 68 1a 00 b4 48 8a 16  0e 00 8b f4 16 1f cd 13  |.h...H..........|
000000a0  9f 83 c4 18 9e 58 1f 72  e1 3b 06 0b 00 75 db a3  |.....X.r.;...u..|
000000b0  0f 00 c1 2e 0f 00 04 1e  5a 33 db b9 00 20 2b c8  |........Z3... +.|
000000c0  66 ff 06 11 00 03 16 0f  00 8e c2 ff 06 16 00 e8  |f...............|
000000d0  4b 00 2b c8 77 ef b8 00  bb cd 1a 66 23 c0 75 2d  |K.+.w......f#.u-|
000000e0  66 81 fb 54 43 50 41 75  24 81 f9 02 01 72 1e 16  |f..TCPAu$....r..|
000000f0  68 07 bb 16 68 52 11 16  68 09 00 66 53 66 53 66  |h...hR..h..fSfSf|
00000100  55 16 16 16 68 b8 01 66  61 0e 07 cd 1a 33 c0 bf  |U...h..fa....3..|
00000110  0a 13 b9 f6 0c fc f3 aa  e9 fe 01 90 90 66 60 1e  |.............f`.|
00000120  06 66 a1 11 00 66 03 06  1c 00 1e 66 68 00 00 00  |.f...f.....fh...|
00000130  00 66 50 06 53 68 01 00  68 10 00 b4 42 8a 16 0e  |.fP.Sh..h...B...|
00000140  00 16 1f 8b f4 cd 13 66  59 5b 5a 66 59 66 59 1f  |.......fY[ZfYfY.|
00000150  0f 82 16 00 66 ff 06 11  00 03 16 0f 00 8e c2 ff  |....f...........|
00000160  0e 16 00 75 bc 07 1f 66  61 c3 a1 f6 01 e8 09 00  |...u...fa.......|
00000170  a1 fa 01 e8 03 00 f4 eb  fd 8b f0 ac 3c 00 74 09  |............<.t.|
00000180  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  f2 c3 0d 0a 41 20 64 69  |............A di|
00000190  73 6b 20 72 65 61 64 20  65 72 72 6f 72 20 6f 63  |sk read error oc|
000001a0  63 75 72 72 65 64 00 0d  0a 42 4f 4f 54 4d 47 52  |curred...BOOTMGR|
000001b0  20 69 73 20 63 6f 6d 70  72 65 73 73 65 64 00 0d  | is compressed..|
000001c0  0a 50 72 65 73 73 20 43  74 72 6c 2b 41 6c 74 2b  |.Press Ctrl+Alt+|
000001d0  44 65 6c 20 74 6f 20 72  65 73 74 61 72 74 0d 0a  |Del to restart..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 8a 01  a7 01 bf 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200
```

Seems i have a problem with bootmgr :( ?

Answer (score 0):

Grub has installed itself on the windows boot sector so Windows cannot boot. Did you select to install it on `/dev/sda1`? Grub was supposed to prevent this, but if you force it manually it can happen (or maybe it's a new bug).

Anyway the only way to repair it is to run `bootrec /fixboot` from a Windows repair prompt which you can get to using a Windows installation DVD or a Windows repair CD.

Does Ubuntu boot fine? If so the above should be all you need. Otherwise you need to edit your question and describe in more detail what is happening.

PS Don't run `bootrec /fixmbr` as this will splat Grub and don't let Windows automatically repair as the same is likely to happen.

PPS You can also repair the boot sector most of the time directly from your Ubuntu install which is easier than booting a Windows repair CD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix

Comment: There is a backup of the boot sector. Testdisk can restore from backup if backup is ok. Screen you want: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#NTFS_Boot_sector_recovery Details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix

Comment: @oldfred Oh yeah, good point. I forgot about that.

Comment: Thanks i try this, and i post update later :) Normally i already repair the boot sector using backup with test disk, without success, i try with the bootrec command

Comment: I update my message with result and a new log ...

Comment: @reyman64 I can't see anything wrong on your latest log... I'd probably try to let Windows repair itself using the repair CD; keep in mind that it will probably remove Grub so you'll need an Ubuntu DVD to reinstall it afterwards.

Comment: Arg, i try to repair automatically using windows repair, failed. I try with /fixmbr

Comment: Arg bootrec /fixmbr then /fixboot remove grub, but windows doesn't start ...

Comment: @reyman64 what happens when you boot Windows, or try to repair? Have you seen [this](http://www.pcworld.com/article/243190/how_to_repair_a_corrupt_windows_7_installation.html)? Check around the web for Windows repair advice, this isn't the right place for that. But when you want to get Ubuntu booting afterwards see [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/14916).